# Optimality Conditions: Mixed Constraints (KKT)

Tags: optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Solve the following optimization problem:

$\max \left\{ x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{\alpha_2}: p_1x_1+p_2x_2 = w, x_1>0, x_2>0  \right\}$

where: $p_1, p_2>0$ and $\alpha_1+\alpha_2=1$.

I need an idea to solve the system

[image]

[image]

Comment: Drop the multipliers on $x_1, x_2>0$. You're not using those correctly anyway, since KKT is for weak inequality constraints. The right approach is to point out that if either of $x_1$ or $x_2$ was zero, the objective value would be zero, and any feasible $x_1,x_2\gg 0$ will give a strictly positive payoff (and  $x_1=w/p_1, x_2=w/p_2$ is feasible, so that set is non-empty), so the solution will have both controls strictly positive at the optimum.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\alpha_{2} = 1 -\alpha_{1}$ and $ x_2 = \frac{w-p_1x_1}{p_2}$ you get :

$$f(x_1) = x_1^{\alpha_1} \cdot  (\frac{w-p_1x_1}{p_2})^{1 -\alpha_{1}}$$

From here you can use the 0 derivative condition to find the value of $x_1$

EDIT :  this works only when $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 > 0$

Comment: thank you for the suggestion

Comment: At least, I tried :D